# How to do a Chromecast API White List URL page?

Tags: chromecast

I want to integrate with the Chromecast Developer API so I want my chromecast(being shipped) whitelisted but you are supposed to supply 2 URLs. What exactly are these for? I might just be confused about how it works. Thanks.

EDIT:

I found [this source to be a good example](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample) to demonstrate how to use it. The HTML in the receiver is what you would have the white listed URL pointing to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Receiver is a HTML5 application (HTML/JS/CSS3) that runs on the Chromecast device.  Your Sender application must send an APP ID to the device, which then looks up the app in a table and loads your page for you.  You then use the App ID in your Receiver (on the Chromecast device) to open a connection to your Sender.

We ask you to provide one or two URL's.  We expect that you'll want to have a development URL, and eventually a production one.  You only need to provide one.

Comment: Alright so if I got this straight your URL is to a web page that contains your code for interfacing with the receiver API? Now, can this be changed if you decide to use a different URL after you have already submitted one?

Comment: Another question I have is why must they be submitted to a white list?  Is Google verifying that there is no illegal/inappropriate content? Or is it to ensure quality(i.e. their App doesn't cause a lot of battery drain by transmitting something)?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Chromecast Device Whitelist Request Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1E-vka5QP8LkF0nbfz-omN1DjNSX1uLGyqHdbpEFh6zg/viewform)

> Please provide at least one receiver URL, we will provide an
>   Application ID for each of them, 2 max (typically, you'll list a
>   production URL and a testing URL)

Comment: I saw that but I still don't know what they are actually used for.  What should this URL contain?  Is it just for identifying purposes like a namespace? Or should it contain something that gets queried?

Comment: It seems that Google maintains a mapping of AppID -> receiver URL.  So when an AppID gets sent to the device from a Chromecast Sender application, the Chromecast either looks up (or has already cached) what URL to go to fetch the receiver html.  Hence, your URL should actually serve the receiver HTML (exactly at the whitelisted url - seems that there are no exceptions)

Comment: @user1132959 .... I am stucking in the same problem... It seems you solved it... Could you please tell me what these url contain??

Comment: @pareshy It should point to a url of your own that contains the following source file:  https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample/blob/master/receiver/receiver.html

Comment: @user1132959 I have properly whitelist my device... I am in pakistan ans dont know what the issue.. I have tried every sample present on Gih Hub but cant find my chromecast device.. can u help me..??

Comment: @pareshy There are several things that could have went wrong. Double check what you can. Network-wise, configuration-wise and all.